# jQuery disable event

Tags: jquery, events, input, keydown

I use jQuery and want to use the input event like this:

```
field.find('textarea').on('input', function(e) {
        console.log('Run when keydown is NOT fired');
});
```

I don't want to run the `keydown` event with it. The reason for that is that I have another event for it, like this:

```
field.find('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
        console.log('Run when key is pressed');
});
```

Right now both events are fired when a key is pressed.

Comment: I don't think you can differenciate betn `input` and `keydown`. You need to use hacks like setting flags.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve, but perhaps just a simple indicator for when the `input` and `keydown` should fire?

```js
var field = $('#div');
var keydown_fired = 0;

field.find('textarea').on('input', function(e) {
  keydown_fired || console.log('Run when keydown is NOT fired');
  keydown_fired = 0;
});

field.find('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
  keydown_fired = 1;
  console.log('Run when key is pressed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

---

Or yet another way, mixing [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and `setTimeout`

```js
var field = $('#div');
function input_func(){
  console.log('Run when keydown is NOT fired');
}

field.find('textarea').on('input', input_func)
.on('keydown', function(e) {
  var that = $(this).off('input');
  console.log('Run when key is pressed');
  setTimeout(function(){
    that.on('input', input_func);
  },10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

---

Note, that in both examples above the `input` event will not fire in case of <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>